# ESS (Emacs): do not change window configuration under R debugging (tracebug)

Tags: r, emacs, ess

I would like to prevent ESS from changing my window configuration but when ESS tracebug is active, entering debugging changes the window configuration.

Suppose three windows in the emacs frame: (1) an R file that defines a function; (2) an R script that calls the function defined in (1); (3): the inferior R ess process. If from (2) I send code to the R interpreter, by default (2) gets replaced by (1) (showing the line to be evaluated, etc). The window showing (3) is left where it originally was; so we actually have the buffer that was in (1) shown twice (at 2 and at 1).

This happens to me under this configuration (starting emacs as `emacs -Q`)

```
(package-initialize)
(use-package ess)
```

I have an additional configuration (all in the spirit of "do not disrupt my window configuration: I'll tell you in what window to start by issuing `M-x R` there"):

```
(setq display-buffer-alist
      '(("*R" . (display-buffer-same-window)))
      )
```

With this configuration, under debug, window (2) now displays the R session (i.e., the inferior R buffer is shown at the original window location 3, and now at 2 also).

The screenshots below show this issue. The first screenshot with the three windows as described (1, 2, 3, from top to bottom).

[image: Three windows, before debugging]

The second screenshot (using the configuration of `display-buffer-same-window`) immediately after evaluating the function into R (`C-c C-f`), and then, from (2), evaluating the line (`C-c C-n`).

[image: Window configuration changed after debugging started]

If I disable tracebug, `M-x ess-tracebug`, no window changes take place, but I do not want to disable following the execution on the window (window 1) that has the code.  I would like to use tracebug but avoid any change to my window configuration: just show (1) with the debugging stuff, but leave (2) alone. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

No answer, but I concur, I find it infuriating that ess changes the window configuration in an haphazard way, even duplicating buffers in another frame.

Comment: For the sake of completeness: since there was no answer to my original post here, I asked this same question a week later in the ESS mailing list, but the answers I got did not solve the issue. This is the link https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/ess-help/2020-December/012822.html

Answer (score 0):

I can no longer reproduce the second problem (tested with ess-20240131.1041). In other words, starting Emacs and having this setting

```
(setq display-buffer-alist
      '(("*R" . (display-buffer-same-window))))
```

does not duplicate the inferior R process window, but can still lead to a possible problem, with a simple solution.

Suppose we start with this window configuration (where function `f1`, from the lower left buffer `f1.R`, has already been evaluated):

[image: Window configuration before ess-eval-line/region-buffer from upper left]

Now, if from the upper left window, the one showing buffer `code1.R`, we use any of `ess-eval-line/region/buffer`,  we end up as

[image: Window configuration before ess-eval-line/region-buffer from upper left]

where the window that was showing `code1.R` is now replaced by `f1.R`.

But that does not happen at all if we the `ess-eval-line/region/buffer-and-go` versions. So problem solved!

I think it is arguably a bug that the window setup is messed with. But it is mostly irrelevant in practice, because if we are debugging, we will want to go to the inferior R process. (I have had the poor habit of using `ess-eval-line/region/buffer` and then moving to the inferior R process; there is no need to do that if I use the `and-go` versions. And I guess this is, thus, a problem that people using the `and-go` would never have encountered.)